# How to get default localization for custom context menu of ScrollBar like the default context menu?

Tags: wpf, localization, controls, scrollbar, contextmenu

I have succesfully created a fully working context menu for the scrollbar control by following this question: [WPF - How to replace the scrollbar ContextMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14691687)

The problem is that the new context menu is always in English, when the original context menu is auto translated (in my case in Italian).

I know that I can use ApplicationCommands for auto translate the menus (for example `Cut`, `Copy`, `Paste` in textboxes), but I was not able to find any commands for scrollbars.

Here a copy of the contextmenu for reference:

```xml
<ContextMenu x:Key="VScrollBarContextMenu" x:Shared="true">
    <MenuItem Header="Scroll _Here" Command="ScrollBar.ScrollHereCommand" CommandTarget="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}" />
    <Separator/>
    <MenuItem Header="_Top" Command="ScrollBar.ScrollToTopCommand" CommandTarget="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}" />
    <MenuItem Header="_Bottom" Command="ScrollBar.ScrollToBottomCommand" CommandTarget="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}" />
    <Separator/>
    <MenuItem Header="Page _Up" Command="ScrollBar.PageUpCommand" CommandTarget="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}" />
    <MenuItem Header="Page _Down" Command="ScrollBar.PageDownCommand" CommandTarget="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}" />
    <Separator/>
    <MenuItem Header="Scroll U_p" Command="ScrollBar.LineUpCommand" CommandTarget="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}" />
    <MenuItem Header="Scroll Dow_n" Command="ScrollBar.LineDownCommand" CommandTarget="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}" />
</ContextMenu>
```

Just place the menu in the style.

```xml
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ScrollBar}" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="18"/>
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{DynamicResource HScrollBarContextMenu}"/>
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource HorizontalScrollBar}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="18"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{DynamicResource VScrollBarContextMenu}"/>
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource VerticalScrollBar}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Original menu

[image: original-menu]

Reworked menu

[image: reworked-menu]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `MenuItem` of the default `ContextMenu` gets its `Header` value from the [resources](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/blob/master/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Wpf/src/PresentationFramework/Resources/xlf/Strings.it.xlf) in the language packs which you can see in the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Primitives/ScrollBar.cs,94bb9ec1ca01ba0d,references):

```
private static ContextMenu VerticalContextMenu
{
    get
    {
        ContextMenu verticalContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        verticalContextMenu.Items.Add(CreateMenuItem(SRID.ScrollBar_ContextMenu_ScrollHere, "ScrollHere", ScrollBar.ScrollHereCommand));
        verticalContextMenu.Items.Add(new Separator());
        verticalContextMenu.Items.Add(CreateMenuItem(SRID.ScrollBar_ContextMenu_Top, "Top", ScrollBar.ScrollToTopCommand));
        verticalContextMenu.Items.Add(CreateMenuItem(SRID.ScrollBar_ContextMenu_Bottom, "Bottom", ScrollBar.ScrollToBottomCommand));
        verticalContextMenu.Items.Add(new Separator());
        verticalContextMenu.Items.Add(CreateMenuItem(SRID.ScrollBar_ContextMenu_PageUp, "PageUp", ScrollBar.PageUpCommand));
        verticalContextMenu.Items.Add(CreateMenuItem(SRID.ScrollBar_ContextMenu_PageDown, "PageDown", ScrollBar.PageDownCommand));
        verticalContextMenu.Items.Add(new Separator());
        verticalContextMenu.Items.Add(CreateMenuItem(SRID.ScrollBar_ContextMenu_ScrollUp, "ScrollUp", ScrollBar.LineUpCommand));
        verticalContextMenu.Items.Add(CreateMenuItem(SRID.ScrollBar_ContextMenu_ScrollDown, "ScrollDown", ScrollBar.LineDownCommand));
        return verticalContextMenu;
    }
}
```

These are internal so you cannot bind to them. If you create your own custom `ContextMenu`, you need to define the translations yourself.